# Insulating Ceiling After Skylight Removal

Tags: insulation, ceiling, roof, skylight

I'm removing 3 skylights from a vaulted ceiling. I'm tired of the leak anxiety and the heat that pours in when it's hot out. I'm hiring someone to do the roof but I'd like to finish off the interior on my own. I'm thinking to remove the wood trim, put in two layers of 2" XPS rigid foam as snug as I can, seal with canned foam and then sheetrock/mud/paint. I'm most concerned about doing something wrong with the insulation. Any tips/suggestions? Here are the skylights that will be removed:

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Comment: and then one day the drywall insert will fell on your head since it is not screwed in.

Comment: Also all that foam will be a firework when it lights off, and the fumes will knock you out and leave you unable to escape.   Foam is n.a.s.t.y.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdItsso3ur0

Comment: Sky lights add value to your home.

Bright rooms add value to your home.

To control the light and heat, install shades.

To close the hole is more elaborate the stuffing foam in it.

To control the leak anxiety have roofing guy inspect it every 2 or 3 Years.

Comment: Once again, knowing where in the world this is would be a help. But assuming they're only a problem in Summer, what's wrong with cutting a slab of rigid foam (maybe 100mm) to fit into the space when it gets too hot? Darned sight quicker, easier, cheaper, and when someone changes their mind, easy to undo!

Comment: I agree with Ruskes & Kyle.  Skylights are generally considered an amenity, for the reasons they mentioned.  Maybe you need to look at upgrading the glass that's in the skylight.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is fine to do what you are planning.

Make sure you add wood framing so that your open space span is no more than 24" on center and use 5/8" drywall (always on 24" span framing- 1/2" drywall will sag with 24" on center framing).

Your rigid insulation is OK but stuffing with batt insulation would also be fine. Put as much insulation as you can in there whether rigid foam or batt. I do not think you need the spray foam at all.

Skylights are nice- until there is a problem. I say if you don't want them anymore then get rid of them.

Comment: Packing as much batt insulation as you can defeats the purpose of batt insulation. The efficacy of batt insulation is severely degraded if its compressed.

Comment: @stevieb - That's only partially true.  Compressed fiberglass batts have the same R-value (actually,it's a bit better) per inch as when it's not compressed. 6" batts are typically R-19, so an R value of 3.2 per inch.  If you compress that batt to 4", you still have 3.2 per inch (or better), but your total R value is 4*3.2=12.8.  It's more important that the cavity be completely filled, even if the insulation is compressed.